# How to reshape multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, unpivot

I have a multiindex `DataFrame` that I want to use its columns as rows and then rename the column to the name of the measure.

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

                0         1         2         3
bar one  0.049409  0.533468  0.528360 -1.437937
    two  2.081377 -0.945535  0.237531 -0.781147
baz one  0.005216  1.158222 -1.178232 -1.470667
    two -0.043834 -0.320864 -1.568357  0.803620
foo one -0.758539 -1.009726  0.139992  0.281034
    two -1.806000  0.206872 -0.728195  1.051045
qux one -1.106591 -0.621868 -1.139649 -0.185527
    two  0.176220 -0.961532  3.587891  0.627658
```

I want to make my dataframe look like this:

```
            measure_name
bar one  0  0.049409
    two  1  -0.945535
    one  2  0.528360
    two  3  -0.781147
```

I can't figure out how to do this. I tried `pd.melt()` but that gets rid of the multiindex and I need to have a way to tie the values from the columns to the index.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you set a seed and please re-print your data? It's easier for us to understand what you want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what a seed is?

Comment: `np.random.seed(42)` Nevermind, piRSquared got it.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry I got the example `df` from the docs and that's what was used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.stack().to_frame('measure_name')

           measure_name
bar one 0      0.562183
        1      2.090766
        2     -0.164342
        3      0.499693
    two 0     -0.174269
        1     -0.997726
        2      0.820774
        3      0.243022
baz one 0     -0.158621
        1      0.520945
        2     -0.356393
        3      0.465289
    two 0     -1.187833
        1      0.886986
        2      1.415511
        3      0.940117
foo one 0     -0.010860
        1      0.126255
        2      1.131045
        3     -0.899853
    two 0     -1.121544
        1     -0.327184
        2      0.074396
        3      0.214501
qux one 0     -0.028317
        1     -1.476114
        2      1.415711
        3     -0.355655
    two 0      0.285167
        1      1.535384
        2      0.074326
        3     -1.860993
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! I had no idea what `.to_frame()` did.

Comment: @rubito you're welcome.  glad I could help.  @ScottBoston also provides a good demonstration of how to use `pd.DataFrame.melt`.  `melt` is a very useful method and his solution does a good job at explaining how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to `melt`, but @piRSquared solution is better:

```
(df.reset_index()
  .melt(id_vars=['level_0','level_1'],value_name='measure_name')
  .set_index(['level_0','level_1','variable'])
  .rename_axis([None]*3)
  .sort_index())
```

Output:

```
           measure_name
bar one 0     -1.442157
        1     -0.738047
        2     -1.724773
        3      0.952186
    two 0      0.470124
        1      0.296891
        2      0.208106
        3      1.050396
baz one 0      1.480720
        1      1.054237
        2     -0.195591
        3      0.994051
    two 0     -0.671022
        1     -0.587526
        2     -0.664228
        3      1.474525
foo one 0     -0.427713
        1     -0.083597
        2     -0.460711
        3      0.646449
    two 0     -0.140055
        1      1.029966
        2      0.431720
        3     -0.902373
qux one 0     -3.126427
        1      0.904205
        2     -0.592984
        3      1.812544
    two 0     -1.450957
        1      1.453259
        2     -0.929294
        3     -0.147798
```